# Как преобразовать 1.0E-6 в нормальный вид 0.000001 в Kotlin или в Java?

Tags: java, kotlin

Код Kotlin вывод: 10E-6

```
fun main() {
val a = 0.000001
println(a)
```

}

Код в Java тоже выводит: 10Е-6

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a = 0.000001;
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Вопрос: как отформатировать вывод, что бы распечатало 0.000001?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.out.println(String.format("%f", a));
```

---

```
System.out.printf("%f\n", a);
```

Comment: Или сразу printf